# Mount NFS share in /Volumes as a drive

Tags: finder, nfs, autofs

Ok, this might be a stupid question to ask, but trying to mount a NFS share (from a Linux machine, if it's worth anything) in a folder that resides in /Volumes never makes the share appear in Finder (not in Volumes anyway).

The folder was made by simply `sudo mkdir /Volumes/folder_name` and the mount was made using autofs like this:

```
/Volumes/folder_name    auto_nfs      -nolock,locallocks,rdirplus
```

I should mention the folder is accessible though the terminal, but it just doesn't show in Finder.

On the other hand, if I modify `/etc/auto_master` to this:

```
/Volumes  auto_nfs      -nolock,locallocks,rdirplus
```

the folder appears, but I loose all my other drives (except the system one and Network)

At the moment, I'm mounting to a regular folder on the system drive which I've symlinked to a folder in /Volumes. Oddly, that works fine, but it does appear as a symlink and it bothers me (and possibly other users).

Comment: Where in Finder are you looking /Volumes or the top level in Finder? ie if you show the fullpath in Finder what is at the top of the window?

Comment: @Mark I need them appear at the top level in Finder (the actual machine), so that other users find them comfortably. I know OS X has a way of telling folders from drives, so just creating a folder in /Volumes does not work out of the box, but I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a boring, technical explanation (which I cannot find right now) for this behavior . I worked around it by adding `/Volumes` to the **Favorites** section in the Finder's sidebar

[image]

Comment: Can you not mount NFS volumes through Finder's "Connect to Server" feature? I don't have an NFS share to attempt with.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem, as I need the drives to be available when I click on the machine (under Devices).

Comment: @bispymusic Yes I can, but it doesn't give me any mounting options, so I loose on performance visibly. Also, to have them automount on startup I have to add them to Login Items.

Comment: @CatalinM Instead of mounting them as Login Items you can auto mount them at system boot time via the fstab file. Read the man page for fstab for more info.

Comment: @HairOfTheDog I thought about that, but last time I checked, there no fstab in /etc, like on my Linux machine. I learned ML uses autofs, so I worked with that. Maybe I missed something along the way?

Comment: @HairOfTheDog Ok, so I checked how things appear in 2 places: 1. Top level in Finder (Computer if you access the Go menu) doesn't show the NFS share. 2. If I go to my Startup Disk (names System in my case) and go into the Volumes folder, I see the NFS Share and it works correctly. Presumably they are the same folders, but...

Comment: @CatalinM the /etc/fstab file does not exist by default. You have to create it.  See this Apple document for more info, specifically page 9 where it describes fstab and how autofs interacts with fstab.  And please up-vote my answer if you found it useful

Comment: @HairOfTheDog This is very interesting, because on my ML machine it was already there (said i should edit it with vifs, but I shrugged away and used nano anyway). On my wife's Lion machine it wasn't there, but I created it. Worked like a charm on both machines. Thanks! PS: You didn't link any Apple document...

Comment: @CatalinM Dang I hate it when I forget to add links.  Here it is:  http://images.apple.com/business/docs/Autofs.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I have spent quite a bit of time figuring out automounts of NFS shares in OS X...

Somewhere along the line, Apple decided allowing mounts directly into /Volumes should not be possible:

/etc/auto_master **(see last line)**:

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static
/-          auto_nfs    -nobrowse,nosuid
```

/etc/auto_nfs **(this is all one line)**:

```
/Volumes/my_mount    -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc nfs://192.168.1.1:/exports/my_share
```

This will not work (anymore!) though it "should".

```
$ sudo automount -cv
...
automount: /Volumes/my_mount: mountpoint unavailable
```

### What's the solution?

It's so easy my jaw dropped when I figured it out.
Basically, we trick OS X into thinking we're mounting * somewhere else. *

When you're talking about paths in just about any environment, the root folder is the highest path you can reach, whether it's `C:\` (windows) or `/` (*nix)

When you're at this path, attempting to reach the parent path, via `..` will keep you at the root path.

For example: `/../../../../` is still just `/`

By now, a few of you have already figured it out.

### TL;DR / Solution:

Change your `/etc/auto_nfs` config from **(this is all one line)**:

```
/Volumes/my_mount    -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc nfs://192.168.1.1:/exports/my_share
```

To **(this is all one line)**:

```
/../Volumes/my_mount    -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc nfs://192.168.1.1:/exports/my_share
```

And re-run the automounter:

```
$ sudo automount -cv
...
automount: /Volumes/my_mount: mounted
```

..... there you go! Technically `/../Volumes` is still `/Volumes`, but the automounter does not see things that way ;)

This configuration persists the mount across restarts, and creates the mountpoint automatically.

## I KNOW, RIGHT?

Comment: I will try it this weekend!

Comment: Did you solve the issue of the shares not being visible in Finder?

Comment: while useful, this does not answer the question of how to make autofs mounted folders show up in the finder...

Comment: I was really hopeful this would still work in macOS 12 (Monterey), but unfortunately it does not. When I run `auto mount -cv`, I get: `automount: /System/Volumes/Data/../Volumes/Files: Operation not permitted` ☹️

Comment: Aye, @JollyRoger, the trick shown here is technically a clever workaround that worked _because Apple was not following the strict guidelines for `/etc/fstab`which _explicitly_ forbid using `/../` (or even spaces...) there. However, Apple _does_ allows us to mount NFS shares under `/Volumes` these days, so I guess that all these tricks are not necessary any longer...

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a volume in terminal, it will be automatically visible in finder

```
mount -v -w -o vers=4,noowners,rw,nolocks,locallocks -t nfs IP_ADDRESS:/ /PATH/TO/SHARED_FOLDER
```

unmount with

```
umount -f /PATH/TO/SHARED_FOLDER
```

Comment: 8 years later this is not a problem anymore, but IIRC the idea behind the question was to have all this done automagically... and once (not throwing it into bashrc or something).