# macOS Sierra: mounting NFS volumes

Tags: macos, mount, automount, nfs, disk-volume

I have a Linux server with a number of NFS exports. I have been mounting them on my Mac by setting up an `auto_nfs` file, and mounting them in `/nfs/…` folders.

I *think* this may the cause of some peculiar behaviour with some applications, which don’t seem to be able to fully traverse these volumes (see [Applications Not Working Properly with Networked volumes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269250/applications-not-working-properly-with-networked-volumes) for details on what I mean by peculiar).

When I mount a SMB share, it appears as a separate volume under my computer, but not so with NFS.

I conclude that things would work better for me if I mount the NFS shares in the `/Volumes` directory. But I can’t:

- The settings in `auto_nfs` require existing directories, and in Sierra, I can’t create one.
- I cannot mount an NFS share using the `nfs:` protocol, since apparently this isn’t supported.

Apparently Sierra changed a few rules regarding the `/Volumes` directory.

How can I mount an NFS share as an ordinary volume? [Mount NFS share in /Volumes as a drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83586/mount-nfs-share-in-volumes-as-a-drive), but:

- It’s an old one and not applicable to Sierra
- The suggestions don’t work here

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Finder, press cmd + k and enter the path to the NFS server/share:

[image: connect to server]

For me this mounted as /Volumes/users-1 (but I already had /Volumes/Users mounted).

```
iMac21:~ user$ df -h /Volumes/users-1
Filesystem               Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
192.168.7.5:/nas/users  5.4Ti  4.8Ti  292Gi    95%  261121 366027775    0%   /Volumes/users-1
iMac21:~ user$
```

If you wanted this to happen on boot you can add it into the login items for your user.

Comment: I had already tried the `nfs:` protocol, as noted in my question, but it didn’t work then. I think my error was in not including the rest of the path. I didn’t know you could add a volume to the login items, so that’s two things I learned. Thanks.

Comment: Greetings from 2019, there's no such UI in here anymore

Comment: Sure there is, enter Finder program first then Cmd + k

Comment: Stupid question: how do I pass parameters to the connection/mount (besides username & password, there are at least two ways to do so — either explicitly on Finder, or implicitly by adding entries on Keychain Access)?

Answer (score 35):

The accepted answer only works when the **NFS server allows connections** on non-reserved ports (i.e. >1024).

The exports man pages say it:

> exportfs understands the following export options: secure
>
> This option requires that requests originate on an Internet port less
>   than IPPORT_RESERVED (1024). This **option is on by default**. To turn it
>   off, specify insecure.

For my CentOS 7.3 box this is not the case by default and I had to add **insecure** to the mount.

So for MACOS client to work **you'll have to add** the `insecure` option to your nfs server in your export

**E.g**.: `/my/export 192.168.5.0/24(insecure)`

If that's not possible: using `mount`you can supply an option to allow reserved ports from the Mac side:
`sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport server:/my/export nfs`

Comment: I spent half a day on this.  I saw the comment but I didn't have CentOS -- I have Ubuntu Mate 16.04.  I finally tried it and that was the issue.

Comment: This should be accepted as the best answer. It saves my day. Thanks!

Comment: @pedz: "secure" is the default on (nearly?) all Linux distros.  It's not at all specific to CentOS, only to normal Linux and Unix servers (as opposed to NAS appliances I guess).

Comment: How "insecure" is it to use allow using ports over 1024? I'm not clear on what's insecure about that at all

Comment: Ports below 1024 are only accessible by the root user on *NIX machines.  My guess is it's "more secure" because you need to have root access to a machine.  In a corporate environment this might be enforceable, but anyone using their own device can have root on that system so really, it's not as secure as the name may suggest.